# Ubuntu Server 16 from ISO in UEFI preseed file

Tags: server, uefi, iso, preseed

Installing Ubuntu Server 16 from ISO in UEFI mode on a Hyperv Gen2 virtual machine with preseed file.  This worked without issues on Ubuntu Server 14.

I am looking for the preseed command to bypass this screen. I answer yes.

[image: screenshot]

Partition disks 
This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating 
System  already installed using  BIOS compatiblity mode.  If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating system later.

If you wish to install UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here.  If  you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system you should choose NOT to force UEFI installtion here.

Force UEFI installation?

Both Seed File have the same issue.

```
Seed File #1  used for  
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label     boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition            select  finish
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite         boolean true
d-i partman/confirm                     boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device  boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm       boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm                 boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite     boolean true
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition       select      Guided - use         entire disk and set up LVM
d-i partman/choose_partition                select      Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman-auto-lvm/no_boot            boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md         boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm                  boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite      boolean true


Seed File #2
# disk partitioning
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label                         boolean     true
d-i partman/choose_partition                                select         finish
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite                             boolean     true
d-i partman/confirm                                         boolean     true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device                      boolean     true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm                           boolean     true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm                                     boolean     true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite                         boolean     true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/no_boot                                boolean     true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md                             boolean     true
d-i partman-md/confirm                                      boolean     true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite                          boolean     true
d-i partman-auto/method                                     string      lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size                            string      max
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label            boolean     true
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the following into your preseed:

> d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true

I ran into same issue with Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 on a blank disk, so I turned on the debug options, and saw in the /var/log/installer/debug file that the "Force UEFI Install" text corresponded to that component.  Adding that to my preseed automated that step for me.

Comment: Note that though this allows the installation to continue, unless your UEFI/BIOS has a fallback option to the other type you may get a boot failure where the system attempts to boot to its default, eg BIOS after installing an EFI OS and fails to find a valid OS. Many UEFI systems support UEFI failing back to a legacy boot, not sure of any that go the other way. I've experienced this on Dell laptops recently after forcing an EFI install on a system that was in Legacy mode, but I could still boot to the EFI OS from the F12 menu.

Comment: Does exactly what it should, thanks very much!